# How to absolutely position a div entirely over another div with overflow:auto

Tags: css, html, overflow, absolute

I have a div that is positioned absolutely in CSS.  That div has overflow:auto so sometimes it shows a scrollbar if it has a lot of content.  I need to completely overlay that div with another div, this one semitransparent so as to completely cover the first div.

The problem is that when a scrollbar is shown in the outer div, the overlay div does not cover it.

My HTML

```
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="content">
          1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>
          6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>
          11<br/>12<br/>13<br/>14<br/>15<br/>
      </div>
      <div id="overlay">
      </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS

```
  div#outer {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
  }

  div#content {
    background-color: lightgray;
  }

  div#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

Run this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pTnXF/4/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Placing the #overlay inside #content and adding a "position:relative" to #content could work.

http://jsfiddle.net/pTnXF/5/

**HTML** changes

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="content">
    1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>
    6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>
    11<br/>12<br/>13<br/>14<br/>15<br/>
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** changes

```
div#content {
background-color: lightgray;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that does not work.  Two reasons -- first, if the amount of content in "content" is small, the overlay only covers the (small) content, not the whole outer box.  Second, even with a lot of content, the overlay does not cover the scrollbar portion of the blue outer box.  Any other ideas?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what is the result you are looking for... Is it something like this ? http://i.imgur.com/nkkpZsr.png

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Another option would be to cover everything other than the scrollbar i.e. the entire scrolling area regardless of how much content is in the scrolling area.  Either would be acceptable.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, so maybe this could do the trick: putting the #content in opacity and the blue border in rgba mode with the same opacity. So it creates the effect of the yellow background covering everything else but the scrollbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/pTnXF/8/

Answer (score 1):

jquery

```
$("#overlay").css("height",($('#outer')[0].scrollHeight));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use jquery